# Is it possible to show a UIAlertView inside a Specific UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I doubt this is possible but, Is it possible to show a UIAlertView inside a UIView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `UIAlertView` is actually another `UIWindow` that goes above you application's main window. The same is valid for the keyboard too.